# X and Y are correlated, errors in both X and Y but error variances unknown; How to predict X|Y or Y|X? Deming, bivariate gaussian ellipses, other?

Tags: correlation, gaussian-mixture-distribution, bivariate, total-least-squares

Seeking relationships between two variable, both with random gaussian errors; ratio of error variances is unknown, no correlation of errors in X and Y, but another unknown variable Z (unmeasured) may be contributing most of the error that result in deviations from regression line. Errors in X, Y, Z are uncorrelated. How to predict X|Y  or Y|X ? Deming Regression, bivariate gaussian distribution, possibly using the main diagonal, or bisecting regression lines for Y vs X and for X vs Y?